# Print rasters count in Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, pyscripter, runtimeerror

I'm trying to print raster batch count number in PyScripter and ArcGIS 10.3
I'm using the next code:

```
import arcpy

carpeta = arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Base_de_datos\Cuencas_raster"

for raster in carpeta:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(raster, ("COUNT")) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            count = row[0]
            print raster + "," + count
```

PyScripter give the next error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 16, in 
RuntimeError: cannot open 'C'

Any idea to how resolve this?

Comment: ListRasters first, iterate through them using rstr=arcpy.Raster(raster) and work with rstr.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you are looping through all the characters in `carpeta` not all the rasters;

i.e.

```
carpeta = arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Base_de_datos\Cuencas_raster"

for raster in carpeta:
    print raster

C
:
\
B
a
```

etc...

You need to use [ListRasters](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//018v0000003w000000) (or arcpy.da.walk).

Secondly, you need to pass a list or tuple of field names. You are passing a single string when you pass ("COUNT") as a single element tuple requires a trailing comma.

Pass ["COUNT"] or ("COUNT",)